# Didn't find class "android.view.menu" on path

Tags: android, menu, program-entry-point, inflate

In my android application i created a menu with two actions save and refresh and called inside another activity.

But it gives this exception, how to resolve this.
**Didn't find class “android.view.menu” on path**

Here is my code ,

This is my main.xml inside main,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="@string/menu_refresh"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_save"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_save"/>

</menu>
```

and this how am calling inside my activity,

```
 @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
     {
         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
     }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_refresh:

                return true;
            case R.id.menu_save:
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Here is my log

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class menu
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class menu
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.SampleApp.AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.onCreate(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.java:28)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     ... 11 more
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.menu" on path: /data/app/android.SampleApp-1.apk
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
07-23 07:48:05.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
```

Comment: add your log or exception

Comment: `But it gives this exception` --> Where is the exception ? Post that .

Comment: As far as I can remember the method is `onOptionsItemSelected()`. Not `onMenuItemSelected()`

Comment: Shaiful is wright. @Shaiful, I think You should put this as answer and earn Your points.

Comment: what is your sdk version

Comment: @Shaiful i tried that too.

Comment: @MohammodHossain Android Developer Tools

Build: v22.0.1-685705

Comment: check your android manifest file . add  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"   android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>

Comment: Do a clean build. Sometimes it fixes xml related issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put the menu.xml file in `/res/menu/menu.xml`

You might get this error when the menu.xml is within `/layout/`

Comment: It is inside res/menu folder only